# How to get an DOM element coordinates after a scrollIntoView?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a series of modals that should be positioned in screen according to a list of DOM Elements.

My main issue is some of them are off of the viewport in some screen sizes so the solution I thought was to scrollIntoView the element and then apply the rect.

```
const modalBody = document.querySelector('.modal-body');
const nextModalBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

const elementsList = ['#a', '#b', '#c'];
const modalInfo = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'];
let count = 0;

myFunction = () => {

 const element = document.querySelector(elementsList[count]);

 element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });

 const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

 const top = rect.top + window.scrollY;
 const left = rect.left + window.scrollX;

 modalBody.innerHtml = modalInfo[count];

 myModal.style.top = top + 'px';
 myModal.style.left = left + 'px';

 count++
}

nextModalBtn.addEventlistener('click', myFunction)
```

The problem is that I think the rect is getting it's coordinates before the scroll, so I tried:

1. Using scrollIntoView without smooth scrolling:

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'auto', block: 'center' });
```

2. Using setTimeout after scrollIntoView:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect);
}, 100);
```

3. I also tried using jQuery offset:

```
let offset = $(element).offset();
let top = offset.top;
let left = offset.left;
```

None of this had worked. The main thing I'm looking for is to achieve the scroll (in the cases it's needed) and then apply the getBoundingClientRect() to get the actual coordinates.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Where do you call the `[count]`? 

Comment: Note that the top voted answer in the Q/A I linked to is actually out of date. There is now a `scrollend` event that only Safari doesn't support yet.